# How can I uninstall Amazon CloudWatch to avoid the cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a free-tier account for AWS (barely to finish) and I would like to remove all services that can cost me. I have checked the Billing Management Console and I got the CloudWatch service running:
[image]

I have checked my AWS resources on https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2globalview/home and I haven't any active resource.

[image]

How can I uninstall it to avoid charges? I don't find this option on the console.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
Problem is located on the Automatic Panels created which won't appear after 2 weeks, as explained on this link: https://repost.aws/questions/QUq5_esmJvTqqeUbDHfgkK0g#ANdyrxFHc5SAydCF0PVG-1AA

Comment: It says 0.00 as a cost. So what is the problem?

Comment: It's 0.00 because I already have the free-tier account

Comment: The AWS free-tier for CloudWatch does not expire, if that is what you are worried about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot uninstall Cloudwatch, what you can do is see services that are actually sending logs or metrics to Cloudwatch and disable them to send logs to Cloudwatch.

But in your scenario, you can see that it says $0.00 and 0-GB-Mo so I dont think any service is sending logs to Cloudwatch, if there was some service, you would have seen the logs storage being consumed like this [image]

Comment: I remove all resources from my Account as you can see in the screenshot but I'm not sure about saving cost without uninstalling CloudWatch service. Is there any chance to remove the metrics which were automatically created by AWS?

Comment: "First 5GB-mo per month of logs storage is free" is because of my free-tier account (checked on AWS free-tier)

Comment: but you can see that there are no data saved for your account 0-GB-Mo... if there was data you would see it, as I have added the image in answer